# Beginner - How can a Node_module access a local config file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, node-modules

I am making adjustments to a node module, which will be used across many repos in my application. This module manipulates and prints a list of messages which are stored in a simple array of strings. I would like each repo to be able to use this module to print that list of "universal" messages, but, if they so choose, they can also use this module to print off additional strings defined locally (maybe in a config file?). I don't know in general how a module is able to access a local file - and I'm not sure what question to ask google.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know how to read from the filesystem, the node module [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) should do the trick. There is documentation how to use it below the table of contents.

As an alternative, `require()` will [read and parse JSON](https://medium.com/@osiolabs/read-write-json-files-with-node-js-92d03cc82824) so you could simply store your config as a JSON file in the project and require it.